# How to access array elements from json_encode in jquery?

Tags: jquery

**Process.php**

```
<?php
    $myArray= array("John", "Rita");
    echo json_encode($myArray);
?>
```

**myJquery.js**

```
$.post('Process.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
    alert(data); // output is: ["John", "Rita"]
    alert(typeof(data)); // output is:  string
    alert(data.length);// output is: 19
    alert(data[0]); // output is:  [           //How can I get John here?

    var person = ["John", "Rita"]; 
    alert(typeof(person)); // output is:  object
    alert(person.length);// output is:  2
    alert(person[0]);// output is:  John
}).fail(function() {
    alert( "Some Problem Occured");
});
```

For an array of jquery, I can easily access array elements, as shown above. But for an array obtained by json_encode in jquery, I am not able to access array elemts. Please, guide me what correction I need in Jquery file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `JSON.parse(data)` or `$.parseJSON(data)` to create a JSON object from the string.

Or you can add parameter to the `$.post();` to tell it, the response will be a json object.

```
$.post('Process.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data){



}, 'json') // <--- here you can add json
.fail(function() {alert( "Some Problem Occured" );});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `jQuery.parseJSON()`

Example:

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( '{ "name": "John" }' );
alert( obj.name === "John" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON Parse like this

```
$.post('Process.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data){
var data= JSON.parse(data);
alert(data[0]);
}
```